# Best way to update code on Azure Linux VMSS from Git using JENKINS

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-git-deployment

I am planning to use Azure VMSS for deploying a set of spring boot apps. I am planning to create a custom linux VM image with all the required softwares/utilities as well as the required directory structure and configure this image in VMSS. We use jenkins as CI/CD tool and Git as source code repo. What is the best way to build and deploy these spring boot apps on VMSS?

I think one way is to write a custom script extension which downloads code from Git repo and then starts these spring boot apps. I believe this script will then get executed every time a new VM is provisioned.

But what about cases where already multiple VMs are running on top of minimum scale instance count. I believe a manual restart will not trigger the CSE script to run on these already running VMs right?

Could anyone advise the best way to handle this?

Also once a VM is deallocated due to auto scale down, what is the best/cost optimal way to back up the log files from VM to storage (blob or file share)?

Comment: Hi @Jacob, is the answer below to enable Automatically tear down virtual machines after every use in the VMSS agent pool settings help you? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: @SukiJi-MSFT, this feature is part of Azure pipeline/devops I believe. I was specifically looking for such a feature in VM scale sets.

Comment: Yes, after configuring the VMSS agent, you could find the button in organization settings/project setting >> agent pool >> VMSS agent pool >> settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable **Automatically tear down virtual machines after every use** in the organization settings/project setting >> agent pool >> VMSS agent pool >> settings. Then, a new VM instance is used for every job. After running a job, the VM will go offline and be reimaged before it picks up another job. The Custom Script Extension will be executed on every virtual machine in the scaleset immediately after it is created or reimaged. Here is the reference document: [Create the scale set agent pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#create-the-scale-set-agent-pool).

[image]

To back up the log files from VM, you could refer to [Troubleshoot and support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#troubleshoot-and-support) about related file path on the target virtual machine.